# Name of specific symmetric Toeplitz matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is there a name for a Toeplitz matrix, which has all diagonal elements equal to let's say a and all off-diagonal elements equal to let's say b? Also, is there any general proof for the eigenvalues of such a matrix?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

This is a constant matrix plus a multiple of the identity. Let $\mathbf{1}$ be the matrix of all $1$s, then the matrix is $b\mathbf{1}+(a-b)I$. The eigenvalues of $\mathbf{1}$ are a single eigenvalue of $n$, and the rest zero, where $n$ is the dimension of the matrix. Adding $a-b$ times the identity simply adds $a-b$ to all the eigenvalues, so the eigenvalues would be a single one at $bn+a-b$, and the rest (of multiplicity $n-1$) are $a-b$. The eigenvector corresponding to the special eigenvalue is the vector of all ones. The remaining eigenvectors can be chosen to be any orthogonal (or not) complement of the vector of all ones.